# How to to disable NewRelic by configuration in.NET

Tags: .net, newrelic

The [NewRelic agent documentation for .NET](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/dotnet/dotnet-agent-configuration) says

> You can also configure two settings in your app's config file: the
>   application's name and a boolean flag to enable or disable the agent.

The first parameter is easy and documented :

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="NewRelic.AppName" value="MyApplicationName" />
</appSettings>
```

But I can't find the name of the parameter that is used to disable the agent.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use this tag:

```
<add key="NewRelic.AgentEnabled" value="true" />
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

If you want to disable New Relic for all applications you can do the following:

```
<configuration xmlns="urn:newrelic-config"
  agentEnabled="false”
  maxStackTraceLines="50"
  timingPrecision="high">
```

Make sure to run an iisreset after making either change to make sure the change is picked up.

Comment: Don't you mean to have agentEnabled="false"?